# Insert into 2nd line after match with shell script

Tags: xml, linux, bash

In the XML, script needs to find `oneFi information="123456789"` and then it needs to insert `<value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="XXXXXX"/>` as shown in the expected.

```
<oneFi information="123456789">
        <bin _list="1">
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="123648"/>
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="547892"/>
        </bin>
      </ondotFi> 
<oneFi information="895781546">
        <bin _list="1">
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="124578"/>
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="546789"/>
        </bin>
      </ondotFi>
```

Expected output:

```
<oneFi information="123456789">
        <bin _list="1">
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="XXXXXX"/>
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="123648"/>
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="547892"/>
        </bin>
      </ondotFi> 
<oneFi information="895781546">
        <bin _list="1">
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="124578"/>
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="546789"/>
        </bin>
      </ondotFi>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: am using bash scripting or shell scripting

Comment: For questions like this, there are a few points that almost invariably come up: use a dedicated tool for this that understands XML (such as xmlstarlet), and secondly, have you tried something that failed? It currently more looks like a problem spec for somebody else to solve than a question about a specific problem you encountered when you tried to solve this.

Comment: i tried so many sed commands, but non are working

Comment: Can you please help me on this?Need to search a string "oneFi institution="12345678"" and need to delete only the  "value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"/" 
Actual: <oneFi institution="12345678">
<bin _list="1">
<value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"/>
</bin>
</oneFi>
<oneFi institution="854784662">
<bin _list="1">
<value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"/>
</bin>
</oneFi>
Expected: <oneFi institution="12345678">
<bin _list="1">
</bin>
</oneFi>
<oneFi institution="854784662">
<bin _list="1">
<value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"/>
</bin>
</oneFi>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This

```
xmlstarlet ed  -s '//oneFi[@information="123456789"]' -t elem -n 'value'   \ 
               -s '//oneFi[@information="123456789"]/value'  attr -n 'maxPAN' -v '19' \
                   attr -n 'minPAN' -v '4' attr -n 'prefix' -v 'XXXXXX'    file.xml
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Simonare, we dont have xmlstarlet package installed.

Comment: Then It is very hard and cumbersome to do that.

Comment: oh okay, thanks @Simonare. I will try my luck

Comment: why does the downvote for?